# How to determine geolocation on mobile devices from browser

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation

I've managed to determine location using html5 geolocation

```
getViaHtml5 = function(done) {
 if(navigator.geolocation) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
  vicinity.lat = position.coords.latitude;
  vicinity.lng = position.coords.longitude;
  done();
 }, function(e) {
  console.warn('ERROR(' + e.code + '): ' + e.message);
  });
 } else {
  console.warn("Browser doesn't support Geolocation");
 }
};
```

Will this work on Blackberry, Samsung, and iPhones? Or will each phone or browser have a different way to determine location? This is from the browser and not from a native app.

Comment: Browser compatibility: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/Using_geolocation#Browser_compatibility

Comment: On phones for high accuracy (GPS is used) and for low accuracy IP address or WiFi is used.

Comment: How would it work for old nokias and blackberrys that don't support html5?